# Horizontalscrollview initial offset value

Tags: android, scrollview

How to set HorizontalScrollView's initial offset value? I used smoothScrolTo() but it is not working.

Please help.

Answer (score 10):

Use **View.getViewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener** to add listener for knowing when scrollview is laid. In the callback you can set scroll.

Use removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this) in the callback to unregister for further events.

```
scroll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout(){
      scroll.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
      scroll.scrollTo(x, y);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not call smoothScrolTo() during onCreate, onStart or onResume. try to give a small delay like this:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HorizontalScrollView sv = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
            sv.smoothScrollTo(1000, 0);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

This works for me, but dose anyone know a better time(e.g. in a listener) for calling smoothScrollTo?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this is via xml.

The trick is add *"Spaces views"* as childs of the *HorizontalScrollView* and set the width of them to the offset you want to have.

Example:

```
<!--BUTTONS ON HORIZONAL SCROLL -->
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view_child_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- This View does the trick! -->
            <Space
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_1"
                style="@style/HorizontalScrollButtons"
                android:text="Btn1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_2"
                style="@style/HorizontalScrollButtons"
                android:text="Btn1" />

            <!-- Keep adding buttons... -->

            <!-- This View does the trick too! -->
            <Space
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

In the example I want a 16dp "margin" so I give the *Space* View a *width* of 16dp.

It will give this...
[image: The way we want]

...instead of this...
[image]

...as starting view.